# Hooking into page specific instance of checkout flow form

Tags: 8, forms, commerce, hooks

I'm working on manipulating the buttons used for the checkout flow of using D8 Commerce 2.
I'm using `MYMODULE_form_commerce_checkout_flow_multistep_default_alter` but its changing both the form buttons on the order information page and the review page.
I want to have different buttons on these two pages.
Is there a way when using a hook to manipulate a form to set it so its page specific?

Comment: I'm not sure if this qualifies as an answer or is a work around but I got what I wanted via matchpath and some good old fashion conditionals:
 ` $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  $patterns = "/checkout/*/order_information";
  $match = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->matchPath($current_path, $patterns);
  if ($match) {
    $form['actions']['next']['#attributes']['value'] = array('Continue');
    $form['actions']['next']['#suffix'] = '<a href="/cart">Cancel</a>';
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Conditionals are still the answer, but turns out there's an easier way that doesn't involve getting the current path:

```
function MYMODULE_form_commerce_checkout_flow_multistep_default_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#step_id'] == 'order_information') {
    Do stuff to the order information page form.
  }
  if ($form['#step_id'] == 'review') {
    Do stuff to the review page form.
  }
}
```